# Aggregate Results In A Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi Friends I had a question about using aggregate results in a trigger. So far my code seems to be working with single records in the UI and passing its assertions. But I feel like I am either missing something or doing it wrong.

If the for loop is passing the value of grouped results at [0] do I need to add code to increment the counter? Otherwise, I assume that when the 5 or 200th record comes through the loop it is still being assigned the value of the grouped results at [0]? 
Here is a sample of the method I am working with

```
 public static void countUniqueRelationshipOwnerEmails(List<relationship_owner__c> roList) {
    //count unique emails related to relationship owner
    system.debug('Relationship owners in trigger = '+ roList.size());
    List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [
            SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(Subject) subjectCount, Relationship_Owner__c
            FROM Task
            WHERE Relationship_Owner__c IN :roList
            GROUP BY Relationship_Owner__c
            ALL ROWS];
    System.debug('Size of aggregate result query ' + groupedResults.size());
    for (relationship_owner__c owner : roList) {
        if (groupedResults.size() > 0) {
            Integer count = Integer.valueOf(groupedResults[0].get('subjectCount'));
            owner.Unique_Emails_Sent__c = count;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll actually want a Map for this:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
        SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(Subject) subjectCount, Relationship_Owner__c Id
        FROM Task
        WHERE Relationship_Owner__c IN :roList
        GROUP BY Relationship_Owner__c
        ALL ROWS]);
for(Relationship_Owner__c record: roList) {
  if(results.containsKey(record.Id) {
    record.Unique_Emails_Sent__c = (Decimal)results.get(record.Id).get('subjectCount');
  } else {
    record.Unique_Emails_Sent__c = 0; // or null, if you prefer
  }
}
```

The "Id" alias is necessary to make the Map automatically map the aggregate result values into the map.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you want to assign count back to relationship_owner__c what you can do is get the results into a map like below and then use the map to get the values where you want to set them.
The advantage of groupby is it also does the order so you will have one on one result for your Relationship_Owner__c and count

```
Map<Id,Integer> aggMap = New Map<Id,Integer>();

for(AggregateResult ag:groupedResults)
            {
                Integer count = Integer.valueOf(ag.get('subjectCount'));
                aggMap.put(Relationship_Owner__c,count); // hold the count at each Relationship_Owner__c level 
            }

for (relationship_owner__c owner : roList) {
    if(aggMap.containsKey(owner.Id)){ // check if it exists
        owner.Unique_Emails_Sent__c = aggMap.get(owner.Id); //get the map value based on the key
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. `keyset().contains(key)` can be written as `containsKey(key)`.