# avoid inner loops with map?

Tags: apex, map, loop

I'm trying getting used to not creating inner loops in apex.

Assume i have a Parent object Account which has child object Contacts.
On Contact object i have a picklist value, with values "abc", "xyz" and "qwe"
If an account has at least one contact record with value "abc", then do nothing, else create
a contact record with that value.
How can this be achieved without inner/nested loops?

Comment: Please elaborate on why would there be an inner loop in the first place. Are you iterating on a list of accounts?

Comment: yes. on a list of accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are a lot of assumptions here - if the value is the SAME for all Accounts, this will be fine, but if you want a different constant per Account, you might need a loop.

In the simplest case, however, you could do this:

```
Account[] accounts = SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, PicklistVal__c FROM Contacts WHERE PicklistVal__c = 'abc') FROM Account];

//This only requires one loop:
Contact[] contactsToInsert = new Contact[]{};
for (Account a : accounts){
  if (a.Contacts.isEmpty()){
    contactsToInsert.add(new Contact(LastName = 'Something', PicklistVal__c = 'abc' ))
  }
}
insert contactsToInsert;
```

Of course, if you start to need anything more complex, you may need more loops.

Comment: +1 but this code could fail with sufficient data skew. A better option would be to use a [`Map<Id, AggregateResult>` solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/238897/2984), which uses fewer rows, less heap, and avoids an error checking `isEmpty` or `size` when contacts on an account exceeds ~2,000.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid ever iterating over the list of related contacts if you want to inspect them, nor is there a problem doing so.

Inner loops should be avoided if you are iterating over the same list each time in the inner loop - in which case a Map may be of use, not if every time its a different set of values/records.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an aggregate result query for this:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> matchingContacts = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
  SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, AccountId Id
  FROM Contact
  WHERE AccountId = :accountsToCheck AND Type != 'abc'
  GROUP BY AccountId
]);
Contact[] contactsToInsert = new Contact[0];
for(Account record: accountsToCheck) {
  if(!matchingContacts.containsKey(record.Id)) {
    matchingContacts.add(new Contact(AccountId=record.Id, Type='abc'/* more fields here */));
  }
}
insert contactsToInsert;
```

This should generally avoid non-selectivity errors, row limits, heap limits, and other surprises you may encounter when querying the contacts as a sub-query.

Comment: Good point - + 1